# date of birth using dropdown lists

Tags: grails

I think this is easy but I cannot find how to do it.
I need to implement a date of birth selection using three dropdown lists, I'm using grails, how is the best way to do it? 
The problem starts for the months, if I select february I would need to show only 28 days in the day dropdown, if I select november for instance only show 30 days, and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`<g:datepicker>`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/datePicker.html).

E.g.:

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date()}"
              precision="day" years="${1930..1970}"/>
```

Comment: thanks! but I currently have a datepicker, and due to bad customer experience I'm trying to change to dropdown lists

Comment: `<g:datePicker>` renders seperate dropdowns for the day, month, year. Personally, I don't think this is very user-friendly, but it's exactly what you asked for

Comment: sorry you were right, that solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: I agree with Don that the dropdowns rendered by `<g:datePicker>` isn't very user-friendly. If you want a calendar dropdown, you may want to look at some plugins: http://www.grails.org/plugins/search?q=date+picker

Answer (score 0):

For selecting dates, I have found using a custom tag lib to be a pretty nice solution. You get a calendar selection in 1 click. It may not be the fastest solution if you are using it for dates of birth, but it keeps it to 1 selection field, which I think is much cleaner.
Create a new tag lib:

```
class JQDatepickerTagLib {

    def jqDatePicker = { attrs, body ->
    def out = out
    def name = attrs.name //The name attribute is required for the tag to work seamlessly with grails
    def id = attrs.id ?: name
    def value = attrs.value
    def displayFormat = attrs.displayFormat
    def datepickerFormat = attrs.datepickerFormat

    def displayFormatString = displayFormat ? displayFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy"
    def datepickerFormatString = datepickerFormat ? datepickerFormat : "mm/dd/yy"
    def dateString = value ? value.format(displayFormatString) : ""

    //Create date text field and supporting hidden text fields need by grails
    out.println "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${name}\" id=\"${id}\" value=\"${dateString}\" />"

    //Code to parse selected date into hidden fields required by grails
    out.println "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \$(document).ready(function(){"
    out.println "\$(\"#${name}\").datepicker({"
    out.println "onClose: function(dateText, inst) {"
    out.println "if(dateText){"
    out.println "var selDate = \$.datepicker.parseDate('${datepickerFormatString}', dateText);"
    out.println "}"
    out.println "}"
    out.println "});"
    out.println "})</script>"
    }
}
```

And then simply in your GSP add this :

```
<g:jqDatePicker name="date"></g:jqDatePicker>
```

and BOOM!! you got a fancy date picker that will be sent back to your controller with any actionSubmit. This date picker will return MM/DD/YYYY, but you can change the format so that it returns each value individually. Happy coding :)